# Amplify init error on Win10 node.js command prompt

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-amplify

I have created an AdministratorAccess user via

```
amplify configure
```

and I did verified my AWS account completely, but I still get this error

```
 Initializing project in the cloud...An error occurred when creating the CloudFormation stack
× Root stack creation failed
init failed
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.239.29.24:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'TimeoutError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '54.239.29.24',
  port: 443,
  time: 2022-02-25T07:55:57.713Z,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true
}
```

My company is using proxy to guarantee security, so could there be something about cli proxy setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is the proxy that prevents me from accessing AWS,

My solution is to type these commands in win10 cmd

```
setx HTTP_PROXY http://username:password@proxy.example.com:1234
setx HTTPS_PROXY http://username:password@proxy.example.com:5678
```

You can read more in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-proxy.html